# Installing OracleSun Java on linux w/o license prompt

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, installation, fedora

I'm trying to automate Java SE install on my linux boxes (Fedora and Ubuntu) and while I can download the rpms/deb files, I cannot get it to install without the interactive license agreement. Is there a way to agree to license via command line without human interaction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: flagged this for SuperUser, it belongs there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto yes to the License Agreement on sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275856/auto-yes-to-the-license-agreement-on-sudo-apt-get-y-install-oracle-java7-instal)

Comment: If anything that one is a duplicate of this one, given the dates they were asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=953779), try

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y java5-sun-jre || :
debconf 'echo SET shared/accepted-sun-dlj-v1-1 true; echo $(read) >&2'
apt-get install -y java6-sun-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that Ubuntu ships with OpenJDK which does not require the "accept license" part.  If that is good enough for you then just run

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

(for recent Ubuntus)

Comment: Hey Thorbjorn, I wish I could use open-jdk/jre. We have two third-party tools that require Oracle/Sun jre.