# Auto yes to the License Agreement on sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer

Tags: java, ubuntu, automation, apt

The Oracle Java package for Ubuntu interactively asks about the License Agreement. So I have to say 'OK' and then 'yes' every time, but I'd like to automate it. What I do is this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
```

Is there a simple way to automate the agreement process without using expect?

Comment: Since you're asking about the usage of the *Ubuntu/Debian* package manager, your question would better fit on [*Ask Ubuntu*](http://askubuntu.com/about) or [*Unix & Linux Stack Exchange*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: On askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190582/installing-java-automatically-with-silent-option

Answer (score 111, accepted):

try this out:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
```

running 3rd and 4th command on my debian 7.1 helps, so I think the same can help on ubuntu as well

Comment: @KJTanaka: you are welcome! please consider to accept it as a solution then ;) or ask more details if it does not solve your entire problem. thanks

Comment: Part of it is documented online at Ubuntu's [add-apt-repository](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html), [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html) and [debconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/debconf-devel.7.html) manuals. You can also use the command line to get the details.

Comment: A small note, the license number changes over time, I had to adjust to `v1-3`, surely it could increment again in the future.

Answer (score 36):

If you are using Ansible for automation you may want to put this into your playbook:

```
tasks:

  - name: add java PPA
    apt_repository:
      repo: "ppa:webupd8team/java"

  - name: accept oracle license
    debconf:
      name: "oracle-java7-installer"
      question: "shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1"
      value: "true"
      vtype: "select"

  - name: install jdk
    apt:
      name: "oracle-java7-installer"
```

**Note:** The `value` argument in `debconf` must be set to `"true"`, including the quotes, as per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275856/auto-yes-to-the-license-agreement-on-sudo-apt-get-y-install-oracle-java7-instal#comment75583581_26591300) by [Roy Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5888928/roy-wood).

Comment: it also works with oracle-java8-installer using ```- name: accept oracle license
  debconf: name='oracle-java8-installer' question='shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1' value='true' vtype='select'```

Comment: Note that it's critical to use quotes on the debconf value!  If you use just "value: true" in your playbook, then the value in the debconf database gets set to "True" and the silent installation will fail with the usual warning of "oracle-license-v1-1 license could not be presented".  You have to specify "value: 'true' " in the playbook to ensure that the debconf setting is set to 'true', which is the exact string the Oracle installer looks for!

Comment: I wish more system configuration questions were answered with Ansible syntax :D

Answer (score 10):

**ppa:linuxuprising/java && oracle-java11-installer**

For anyone using the Linux Uprising Java 11 installer that stumble across this, see these:

1. https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java
2. https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-install-oracle-java-11-in-ubuntu.html

Instead of the commands in the answer (as listed on their site), you want this:

```
echo oracle-java11-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 select true | \
sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
```

Here's my Docker setup for an Ubuntu 18.04-based container:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:linuxuprising/java && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java11-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java11-installer && \
    apt install oracle-java11-set-default
```

Comment: I can confirm this answer also works for java 12. Note the license name is different than the accepted answer: v1-2, not v1-1.

Comment: Now it says `'oracle-java11-installer' has no installation candidate`

Comment: And adding ppa `linuxuprising/java` didn't work with me, I used this fix:
`echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-java.list && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 73C3DB2A`

Answer (score 3):

For Java 11 you can use this:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 select true | debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 seen true | debconf-set-selections
apt-get update && apt-get install -y oracle-java11-installer
```

This works perfectly in a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Just like other answers, following works for the JDK 17

**accepted-oracle-license-v1-3** - in specific

```
echo oracle-java17-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-3 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
```